# JDBC connection from Databricks to SQL server

Tags: sql, jdbc, azure-sql-database, databricks

I have a scenario where I need to trigger Stored procedure in the SQL server from Databricks. With the spark SQL connector,I can able to SELECT but not trigger the stored procedure.

I am trying to connect Java JDBC but whenever I execute it says "NO Driver found"

I have uploaded the driver (mssql_jdbc_8_2_2_jre11.jar) to the Databricks cluster.

- Tried Code:

  import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet}

  DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());

  Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")

  val conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:xxxx.database.windows.net;databaseName=yyyy-db;user=admin;password=pwd;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8")

Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Need suggestion on the same and is there a way to execute stored procedure from Databricks using Scala / Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have uploaded the driver (mssql_jdbc_8_2_2_jre11.jar) to the Databricks cluster.

That shouldn't be necessary and may be the cause of your problem.  It's already included in the Databricks runtime, as documented in the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/releases).

Or more likely your url just messed up.  You can copy-and-paste from the connection string settings in the Azure portal.  Should be something like:

`jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx.database.windows.net .. .`

This works for me:

```
%scala
import java.util.Properties
import java.sql.DriverManager

val jdbcUsername = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "kv", key = "sqluser")
val jdbcPassword = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "kv", key = "sqlpassword")
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

// Create the JDBC URL without passing in the user and password parameters.
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=AdventureWorks;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"

val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
val stmt = connection.createStatement()
val sql = """

exec usp_someproc ...

"""

stmt.execute(sql)

connection.close()
```

Also this

```
%scala
import java.sql.{Connection, DriverManager, ResultSet}

DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver());

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this post. I'm new to Java / Scala / Spark / Databricks and this info so much harder to find than expected. This works, it should be marked as the solution.

Comment: I don't see that the inclusion of the driver is mentioned anywhere in the release notes. Can you point out where it is mentioned?

Comment: Earlier versions enumerated the Java libraries that they ship in each version.  Looks like they discontinued that.  But that JDBC library is still there and it’s a dependency for the Synapse Spark driver.

Comment: You're a savior. Thanks!!