# Executing Stored Procedure in Databricks when using Azure Apache Spark connector

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Following example from Azure team is using [Apache Spark connector for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/spark/connector?view=sql-server-ver15) to write data to a table.

**Question**: How can we execute a `Stored Procedure` in an `Azure Databricks` when using `Apache Spark Connector`?

```java
    server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER_ADDR}"
    database_name = "database_name"
    url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"
    
    table_name = "table_name"
    username = "username"
    password = "password123!#" # Please specify password here
    
    try:
      df.write \
        .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .option("url", url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", username) \
        .option("password", password) \
        .save()
    except ValueError as error :
        print("Connector write failed", error)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC connection from Databricks to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065607/jdbc-connection-from-databricks-to-sql-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run stored procedure on SQL server from Spark (Databricks) JDBC python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670313/how-to-run-stored-procedure-on-sql-server-from-spark-databricks-jdbc-python)

Comment: 2nd link shows how to do that from PySpark

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft David, I'm using `python` and have no knowledge of scala. I was wondering if there a python version of your suggested solution.

Comment: If the ODBC driver is installed you can use pyodbc.  But the scala is boilerplate.